# grails 4 groovy's date enhancement methods missing

Tags: grails, groovy, java.util.date, grails-4

In a previous version of grails I was able to use the groovy enhanced version of java.util.Date found here [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html).

After upgrading to grails 4, all those methods throw no signature of method  on java.util.Date. Somehow the groovy additions aren't being picked up.

```
  def fdate=new Date();
  out << fdate.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
  //No signature of method: java.util.Date.format()
```

Comment: Do you have `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil` in your project?

Comment: Consider not using `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a dependency to `groovy-dateutil` to your `build.gradle`:

```
runtime 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil'
```

The relevant extension method is defined at https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-dateutil/src/main/java/org/apache/groovy/dateutil/extensions/DateUtilExtensions.java#L526-L528, which is in the `groovy-dateutil` library.

Comment: Why it was excluded from standard build.groovy?  Does this methods impair performance?

Comment: "Why it was excluded from standard build.groovy?" - Most applications don't use it so we don't add it by default.  "Does this methods impair performance?" - The presence of that library by itself doesn't impair performance but if it isn't being used, there is no reason to carry it around.

Comment: Wasted time hunting this down...thanks for the solution. Still don't see why it's not part of the base Groovy.... Believe me it is useful.... what data do you have for the "Most applications don't use it"?  Thx

Comment: `"Wasted time hunting this down"` - I am really sorry about that.  We put it in the release notes and documentation.  `"what data do you have for the ..."` - The library is specifically for manipulating and otherwise working with Dates.  Many applications don't do that.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown where are the release notes? I'm having trouble locating mention of this in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: "where are the release notes?" - The release notes for Groovy 2.5 are available at http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html. "I'm having trouble locating mention of this in the documentation." - It is mentioned in the first bullet under "Breaking Changes".