# Why is Groovy's date extensions not available in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

When attempting to use the Groovy date extension, clearTime(), the error returned is Cannot find matching method java.util.Date#clearTime(). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.

When I use:

```
def date = new Date()
date.clearTime()
```

I get the previous error.

This happens if I use compileStatic or at runtime if I do not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grails 4 groovy's date enhancement methods missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57548284/grails-4-groovys-date-enhancement-methods-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Groovy's date extensions not available in Micronaut?

Groovy's date extension is available in Micronaut.  The date extensions may be used in any JVM app (including Micronaut).  I expect you are missing a dependency on the `groovy-dateutil` library, which is the library which provides that method.

You should add a dependency on `'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:3.0.5'` to your project.

Comment: The question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57548284/grails-4-groovys-date-enhancement-methods-missing was asked in the context of Grails, not Micronaut, but the exact same issue applies in both contexts.